# How to overload method with different typed Lists?

Tags: java, overloading, type-erasure

Is it possible to overload a method where the parameter is a `List<>` of different types?

For example, I am looking to create two methods defined as such:

```
public void getChanges(List<TypeOne>){}
public void getChanges(List<TypeTwo>){}
```

However, since both methods accept a `List`, there is a conflict. Is there any way to make the methods take the object type **within** the list into consideration?

It seems odd to me that the compiler does not realize the signatures are indeed different as a `List<TypeOne>` is not the same as `List<TypeTwo>`.

Comment: The short answer, both are seen as `List<Object>` so there is no overload possible here.

Comment: you can do it like this `public void getChanges(List<TypeOne>){}` and `public void getChanges(List<TypeTwo>, int a){}` where `int a` is some useless value.

Comment: @nimi0112 - Thank you for the workaround, but that definitely seems like a really bad habit to get into...

Comment: @Zephyr - It may be a bad habit but it does not mess with the code and no other variable allocation required and it's use can be easily explained in comments.

Comment: @nimi0112 "does not mess with the code" aside from introducing useless arguments, leaving future readers of the code wondering what on earth it means. Renaming the methods is vastly preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to give them different names, because the methods above have the same **erasure**.

Information about concrete generic types is not stored in the runtime, so if you keep the signatures above JVM will not be able to realise what method should be called in the runtime if you pass any list of objects as an argument.

For more information about **erasure**, please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Could you add more information than just the link ? See [answer] about links.

Comment: Sure! I'll add more details